# Laravel CRUD problem with saving my info in the database

Tags: laravel, crud, homestead, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

I have a problem with saving my info in the database Laravel CRUD, I write new info on the create page and he goes to the index page, and the info doesn't see.
[after I press submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqKnB.png)

[I don't see my new info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAUgF.png)

my create.blade.php (first image page):

```php
<p>It works</p>
<form metod="post" action="/projects">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <div>
    <textarea type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
<button type="sumbit">Sumbit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

my index.blade.php (second image page):

```php
<p>It works</p>
@foreach ($projects as $project)
<li>{{ $project->title}}</li>>
@endforeach
```

my web.php

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/welcome', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@welcome');
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@users');
Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@business');
Route::get('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index');
Route::post('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store');
Route::get('/projects/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create');


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

my ProjectsController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    $projects = \App\Models\Project::all();
    return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
    return view('projects.create');
    }
    public  function store()
    {
    $project = new Project();
    $project->title = reqeust('title');
    $project->description = request('description');
    $project->save();
    return redirect('/projects');

    }
}
```

my Project.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Comment: `Project` fillable https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: fillable is not required as this is not mass assignment @Kamlesh Paul

Comment: You have a typo here: `metod="post"`, it should be `method="post"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelled request wrong in your `ProjectsController` `store()` function, it should read,

```
$project->title = request('title');
```

That may not entirely be the solution, you may need this instead

```
public  function store()
{
$project = new Project();
$project->title = request()->input('title');
$project->description = request()->input('description');
$project->save();
return redirect('/projects');

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: ok good, but nothing changed( i write name and description and press submit, throws me on page index and on-page index no new info(

Comment: @Mineral its because of the typo in your form as mentioned in the comments

Comment: @lagbox is correct, `<form metod="post" action="/projects">` should be `<form method="post" action="/projects">`

Comment: @Mineral consider using an IDE like Atom or PHPstorm to help catch these typos.